# PHP Delete from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to delete a selected row from my database, but I don´t know how to accomplish it. I am completly new to this topic, so it would be really nice, when you could explain to me. 
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> PHP F1 - Datenbank</title>
    <style>
        button {
            margin:5px;
            margin-left:-0px;
        }
        .insert {
            position:relative;
            margin:0px;
            margin-bottom:5px;
            margin-top:-25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Insert Dokument für deine Datens&auml;tze ! </h2>
<form action="F1_PHP.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="jahr" placeholder="Albert-Park"> <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="sieger" placeholder="Australien"> <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="schnellster" placeholder="Melbourne"> <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="strecke" placeholder="Laenge"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="formdaten" class="insert" value="Insert">  <br>
</form>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Strecke</th>
        <th>Land</th>
        <th>Stadt</th>
        <th>L&auml;nge</th>
    </tr>
<?php

try {

    $server = 'mysql:dbname=f1;host=localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $options = array
    (
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    );
    $pdo = new PDO($server, $user, $password, $options);

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if ($pdo){
        if (isset($_POST["formdaten"])) {
            $jahr = $_POST["jahr"];
            $sieger = $_POST["sieger"];
            $schnellster = $_POST["schnellster"];
            $strecke = $_POST["strecke"];

            $eintrag = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO Strecke
            (pk_Strecke, Land, Stadt, Laenge) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);");


            $eintrag->execute(array($jahr, $sieger, $schnellster, $strecke));

            if ($eintrag == true) {
                echo "Eintrag war erfolgreich";
            } else {
                echo "Fehler";
            }
        }
    }
    }
catch (PDOException $error) {
    echo 'Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: ' . $error->getMessage();
}

try {
    $query= 'SELECT pk_Strecke, Land, Stadt, Laenge FROM Strecke';
    $stmt   = $pdo -> query($query);
    $deleteString = "";

    while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo ' <td>'."<input type='radio' name='markiert'>".'</td>';
        echo ' <td>'. $row["pk_Strecke"].'</td>';
        echo ' <td>'. $row["Land"]. '</td>';
        echo ' <td>'. $row["Stadt"]. '</td>';
        echo ' <td>'. $row["Laenge"]. '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
catch (PDOException $error) {
    echo 'Fehler beim Lesen der Daten ' . $error->getMessage();
}

?>
<br>

    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
    <?php
        // delete button

    ?>

    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
    <?php
        //Update button

    ?>
<br>
<table border="1">
<tr>
   <th> </th>
   <th> Jahr               </th>
   <th> Sieger             </th>
   <th> Schnellste Runde   </th>
   <th> Strecke            </th>
</tr>
 <?php
 try {
   $query= 'SELECT pk_Jahr,Sieger,SchnellsteRunde,pk_fk_Strecke
                 FROM Rennen join Strecke on pk_fk_Strecke = pk_Strecke
                   order by pk_Jahr';
   $stmt   = $pdo -> query($query);
    while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
      {
       echo '<tr>';
         echo ' <td>'."<input type='radio' name='markiert'>".'</td>'; 
         echo ' <td>'. $row["pk_Jahr"].'</td>';
         echo ' <td>'. $row["Sieger"]. '</td>';
         echo ' <td>'. $row["SchnellsteRunde"]. '</td>';
         echo ' <td>'. $row["pk_fk_Strecke"]. '</td>';
       echo '</tr>';
       }
    echo '</table>';
}
catch (PDOException $error) {
    echo 'Fehler beim Lesen der Daten ' . $error->getMessage();
}   
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate every tip from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a good idea of how to set up the PHP side of things, so I'll just deal with the SQL part.

The general syntax for a delete using PDO and MySQL would be as follows:

```
$query = "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE Field = :value";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt-> bindParam(':value', $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

The field you're querying against on that table needs to be unique, unless you're wanting to delete multiple rows (so best to use a primary key for the field and value).

It looks like you're using racing circuits in one of your tables, so your table may look like this (I'll call the table "circuits"):

id (primary key), circuit, country.

You may have the following data in it:

1, Albert Park, Australia
2, Silverstone, Great Britain
3, Adelaide, Australia

To delete Albert Park from the database, you'd run this:

```
$value = 1;
$query = "DELETE FROM circuits WHERE id = :value";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt-> bindParam(':value', $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

To delete all circuits in Australia (2 of the 3 above records):

```
$value = "Australia;
$query = "DELETE FROM circuits WHERE country = :value";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt-> bindParam(':value', $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

You could pass the value for $value through a form, and using bindParam() protects against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following statements:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `Rennen` WHERE `pk_Jahr` = :id_to_delete";
$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array( ":id_to_delete" => 'Value of pk_Jahr of the row to delete' ) );
```

Comment: You should ***explain*** your answer.